# Avoid trailing slash in Flask when bundling multiple apps using DispatcherMiddleware

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

**wsgi.py**

```
application = DispatcherMiddleware(home.create_app(), {
    '/abstract': abstract.create_app(),
    '/sentiment': sentiment.create_app(),
})
```

**abstract/__init__.py**

```
def create_app(settings_override=None):
    app = factory.create_app(__name__, __path__, settings_override)


    @app.route("/")
    def abstract():
        return "Abstract"
```

Hi I am building a set of small standalone apps that I want to bundle in a single project. `https://company.io/abstract` and `https://company.io/sentiment` are the urls of interest to me. Unfortunately, these root level urls within the standalone packages get a trailing slash attached to them and I cannot find a way to get rid of it.

I tried appending the magic `strict_slashes` everywhere. But that does not seem the solution to achieve this if you leverage Werkzeug's `DispatcherMiddleware`. Someone knows how to get rid of the trailing slash at the root? i.e. `https://company.io/abstract` and not `https://company.io/abstract/`.